# No Ethernet connection with Lenovo Docking Station Thunderbolt

Tags: networking, lenovo, ethernet

I'm using a Lenovo X13 Yoga Laptop connected to a Lenovo Universal Thunderbolt 4 Dock with a thunderbolt cable. Further the docking station has two screens and an Ethernet cable attached. The laptop is running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and the kernel version is `5.13.0-37-generic`

Today Ubuntu asked me to install new updates. After the updates I restarted the laptop and then my Ethernet connection from the Docking station to the LAN didn't work anymore. However if I connect the Ethernet cable directly to the laptop I get access to the internet.

According to the history.log it installed the following stuff:

```
Start-Date: 2022-03-22  09:20:48
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-image-5.13.0-37-generic:amd64 (5.13.0-37.42~20.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-37-generic:amd64 (5.13.0-37.42~20.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.13.0-37-generic:amd64 (5.13.0-37.42~20.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-5.13.0-37-generic:amd64 (5.13.0-37.42~20.04.1, automatic), linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-37:amd64 (5.13.0-37.42~20.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.13.0.35.40~20.04.20, 5.13.0.37.42~20.04.22), linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.13.0.35.40~20.04.20, 5.13.0.37.42~20.04.22), linux-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.13.0.35.40~20.04.20, 5.13.0.37.42~20.04.22)
End-Date: 2022-03-22  09:21:14

Start-Date: 2022-03-22  09:21:17
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-104.118, 5.4.0-105.119)
End-Date: 2022-03-22  09:21:17
```

I checked in the BIOS if it is still forwarding the MAC address from the laptop to the docking station, what it does. I'm not a Linux pro, so I can't really tell what went wrong. I guess one of the updates did something bad. The previous kernel was `5.13.0-35-generic`. Should I try to downgrade to that? Would that break anything? I haven't installed anything new except the updates from above. Any ideas?

EDIT: I downgraded the kernel to `5.13.0-35-generic` and now the ethernet connection is working again. Where do I find the kernel repositories for the two mentioned kernel versions for trying to figure out where the problem might be? I can't find the kernels I have to do with on https://kernel.ubuntu.com/ They start enumerating from 5.13.1 but I have 5.13.0

Comment: More than likely you need a firmware update for the dock, or a BIOS update for the laptop.

Comment: Hello. I also notice you have Ubuntu 20.04.1  An up to date system would be 20.04.4 so way behind in updates.

Comment: @David My fault. I gave the output of `uname -a` Which is the kernel. But it is Ubuntu 20.04.4. `lsb_release -a` shows 20.04.4

Comment: OK but there has never been a kernel that starts with 20.

Comment: @David It is what `uname -a` outputs. 5.13.0-35-generic #40~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 7 09:18:32 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Kernel 5.13.0-35-generic

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 22.04 and a Lenovo Thinkpad. I found out that in my BIOS setup there is an option set that prevents new Thunderbolt devices from connecting to the computer. (Screens worked, but neither ethernet nor any USB device on the dock worked.)

I solved it by booting once into a parallel Windows installation, there I was asked by the Thunderbolt software if I want to accept that new device. I answered with something like "yes, permanently", and after reboot to Linux the dock also worked there (ethernet as well as USB).

Don't know if you could accept the device also from the BIOS setup, I don't think it is possible from within Linux.

Another alternative would be that you allow any Thunderbolt devices from within your BIOS setup.

Comment: Btw I have Kernel version 5.15.0-47-generic at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem and it worked for me to do just an

```
sudo apt update
```

and after that an simple restart

```
shutdown -r
```

I hope it will solve your problem :)